# Dispatch function doesn't update initial state, React Redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm learning Redux for React Native, and I'm trying to make an app in which you type `name` and `lastname`,and by pressing the button it starts the functions `addItem` which adds `name`, and `lastname`  to the array `list`, and `sumbitItem`, which launches the `dispatch` function, the problem is that when I launch the `dispatch`, it doesn't update initial state array `list`, it just doesn't do anything.

```
export class List extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: this.props.list,
      name: '',
      lastname: '',
      
        };
  }


  addItem = ( name, lastname ) => {   
  let list = this.state.list
    const  item = {
        key: Math.random(),
        name: name,
        lastname: lastname,
      };
      list.push(item);
      this.props.updateList(list);
  };


  render(){
    return(
 
        <Button onPress={() => this.addItem()}>
         <Text>Press Submit</Text>
        </Button>

    )}
```

**Reducers**

```
const initialState = {
  currentUser: null,
  list: [],
};



    export const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type){
          case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
              ...state,
              currentUser: action.currentUser,
            };
          case 'ADD_ITEM': 
          return{
            ...state,
            list: action.list,
          }
          default:
            return state
      }
      
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few improvements need to be done.

1. You need to wrap your component in **connect**
2. You need to create and Action.js

Component

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { updateList } from './action'

export class List extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: this.props.list,
      name: '',
      lastname: '',
      
        };
  }


  addItem = ( name, lastname ) => {   
  
    const  item = {
        key: Math.random(),
        name: name,
        lastname: lastname,
      };
      this.setState({ list: [...this.state.list, item]})
  };

  submitItem = ( list ) => {
    () => this.props.updateList(list);
     this.props.navigation.navigate('list');
  }

  render(){
    return(
 
        <Button onPress={() => {this.addItem(this.state.name, this.state.lastname); this.submitItem(this.state.list)}}>
         <Text>Press Submit</Text>
        </Button>

    )}

mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return state
}

mapDispatchToProps = {
  updateList
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(List );
```

Action.js

```
export const updateList = (list) => {
  return { type:"UPDATE_LIST", payload:list}
}
```

Reducers

```
const initialState = {
  currentUser: null,
  list: [],
};



    export const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type){
          case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
              ...state,
              currentUser: action.currentUser,
            };
          case 'UPDATE_LIST': 
          return{
            ...state,
            list: [...action.payload],
          }
          default:
            return state
      }
      
    };
```

**You can check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-sample-3fudn), I have added end-to-end working code here.**

Comment: thanks for your answer, I made the necessary changes and now it returns in the terminal  `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.state')`

Comment: and also `mapStateToProps() in Connect(List) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.`

Comment: You can check this codesandbox, I have added end-to-end working code here. https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-sample-3fudn

Comment: thanks for your help, I edited the code above so you can see the changes I've made based on the code you gave me in the codesandbox, the problem now is that when I run the code it returns `list.push(item) is not a function`, I've tried many times but I couldn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out what you're going to use global state (redux) for vs what you're using local state (this.state...) for.

It looks like you would like to set the list from local state to global state in submit item (although you called the action ADD_ITEM). In this case you need to pass the list to the reducer:

```
  submitItem = ( list ) => {
    this.props.dispatch({type:'ADD_ITEM', payload: list});
     this.props.navigation.navigate('list');
  }
```

Then in your reducer:

```
          case 'ADD_ITEM': 
          return{
            ...state,
            list: action.payload,
          }
```

This of course still won't be visible from your component but it should put the list into global state.
If you want to control the list from global state rather than component state then you need to refactor the code so that ADD_ITEM actually adds the item into redux list, rather than your local state (which is what your current implementation is doing).